# How to disable text format options in CKEditor

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I wish users don't have the option which text format they want to use as shown here:
[image]

I have been playing around with the [better formats](https://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module, Currently only works on Field API fields on fieldable entities implementing core style text processing. So this module only makes sure with which text format they will start off editing with, so this dCurrently only works on Field API fields on fieldable entities implementing core style text processing.oesn't do anything at all, as the users still have the option to choose which text format they would like to choose.

Besides hiding this option with CSS, is there another way to disable this option for specific users?

Answer (score 1):

The simplify module will allow you to hide text format selection, and a lot of other bling too: https://drupal.org/project/simplify

The simplify module allows you to hide the text format selection globally on all content types, as in the attached screen. Alternately, you can disable text format selection for each content type individually.

[image]

I've really only used it one one site so far, but haven't had any trouble.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: How so? It's worked fine in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option called "Text processing" in the content type's body field settings (`Content types > YourContentType > Manage fields > Body > Edit`). If you check "Plain text", it should disappear.

[image]

Comment: I can't follow you, if you mean managing the content types of the structure. It's the module itself.

Comment: I don't think you need a module for this. You can do it directly via the Drupal interface. You are working with a content type, right?

Comment: Yes, but I am working with CKEditor, within the manage fields there is not option to disable the text-format

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 9. Use can set the allowed_formats. If there is only one format, it will hide the select box

```
'body' => [
        '#type' => 'text_format',
        '#format'=> 'full_html',
        '#allowed_formats' => ['full_html'],
      ]
```